# How to draw text on Canvas

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

Currently, I am able to add various `Shape` on `Canvas` by

```
canvas.Children.Add(line);
canvas.Children.Add(polyLine);
//...
```

But, how can we draw text, with various font size, font type, ... on it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `TextBlock` to canvas's children.

Answer (score 0):

[In this example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/InkPen-sample-in-CSharp-189ce853), they are not drawing on canvas but detecting pointer movements and than adding line shapes to the canvas. So I think you cannot draw on canvas directly. There is another post that talks about [Drawing Context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingcontext.aspx), so you might want to look into it.